# Why don't all programs recognize certain drives that have mounted at startup?

Tags: fdisk, gnome-disk-utility

My internal Samsung 970 EVO 500 GB drive contains my OS.  I have two Crucial internal solid-state drives that contain files, and have defined symlinks so that I can get to them from ~/Documents.  I've set up the options, using Gnome Disks, to mount those drives at startup.  Despite this, I've noticed Gnome Disks doesn't put entries for those drives in `/etc/fstab`.

When I boot, certain programs - like InSync, which I use to sync files to Google Drive -- cannot find the Crucial drives.  Also, my symlinks show as archived files when I look at them in the terminal.  To get the symlinks active, I have to navigate to the drives in Nautilus.  Once I navigate to the drives in Nautilus, the symlinks show up as live in the terminal and my programs like InSync can be restarted and have no difficulty finding the drives.

What's going on here?  Why isn't Gnome Disks updating `/etc/fstab`, and how do I get my drives to be recognized upon startup?  Again, Gnome Disks is set up with the option to mount at startup checked, for all drives.

Comment: Hey @Dan Green, just realised you wanted Symbolic Links as opposed to drive maps. I've added an answer on mounting the drives manually. Let me know if this *doesn't* suit your requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *easiest* way to fix this is to just mount them in your `/etc/fstab` as you see fit. To perform this, open up the terminal using `ctrl` + `alt` + `t` and follow along:

Issue `blkid` to get the `UUID` of the drive you want to map:

```
sudo blkid
/dev/nvme0n1p1: UUID="cf426a4a-efcb-4fdf-8d5b-16c351b6120f" TYPE="ext4" PARTLABEL="Backups" PARTUUID="33ff5cc6-8195-4fe9-a3bb-64f842972bfc"
```

From here, I need to grab my **UUID** and append this to my `fstab` file as such (note: these are 'defaults', you can append these with the options you want):

```
sudo nano /etc/fstab
```

For me, I made a directory under `/mnt/Backups` and wanted to mount there:

```
# Backups SSD:
UUID=cf426a4a-efcb-4fdf-8d5b-16c351b6120f       /mnt/Backups    ext4    defaults,auto   0       0
```

Doing this, my drive is auto-mounted and can be accessed via `/mnt/Backups` as required:

```
╰─$ df /mnt/Backups 
Filesystem     1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/nvme0n1p1 491209736 297953008 168235032  64% /mnt/Backups
```

You can also use the `chmod` and `chown` command to set the permissions as you see fit. More help can be [found here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Fstab)

Comment: I noticed fstab doesn't have labels for the partition.  I don't know whether the referring programs need the labels or not....is there an option for ext4 filesystem to specify the label in /etc/fstab, or does Gnome somehow take care of that?

Comment: for example, if blkid yields  

/dev/sda1: LABEL="Files" UUID="eebdacc5-8701-4b9d-b256-0ba5f9074db7" TYPE="ext4" PARTLABEL="Files" PARTUUID="515a684f-acf5-4ee5-9083-2fa8194ea515"     

it seems to me the /etc/fstab entry should be 

UUID=eebdacc5-8701-4b9d-b256-0ba5f9074db7 /mnt/eebdacc5-8701-4b9d-b256-0ba5f9074db7 ext4 nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show 0 0

....or should the mount point be /mnt/dan/Files, which is where gnome disks says it is mounted?

Comment: or can I use both LABEL"xxx" UUID="xxx" in my fstab entry?

Comment: Hey @DanGreen - you're mounting the drive to a friendly file, so you could do something like: `UUID=$yourid /home/dan/Documents/drive ext4 ...` and then you just use `/home/dan/Documents/drive` to access the HDD.

Comment: Perhaps [this video](https://youtu.be/A8ITr5ZpzvA?t=99) gives a better understanding. Not sure if I'm misinterpreting your question either.

Comment: ok, thanks....the video was helpful.  I looked at where the drives were mounted, and they were mounting to /media/...  rather than /mnt/.... so I changed the mount point in my suggested /etc/fstab entry in my earlier comment to /mount/<user>/<Label> and rebooted and it worked; it all mounted at startup.    Interestingly, the drives hadn't been mounting the way I had specified in the gnome disk utility, raising the question:  What is the Gnome disk utility for?  Evidently, it doesn't write to fstab and its settings don't seem to get checked at startup.

Comment: Hey @DanGreen - I'm glad this worked for you. Please, if it did, mark the question as the answer. As for the relation to `/mnt` and `/media` I *believe* `/media` is a protection folder that has all physically attached devices stored their with their UUID and thus you need root to modify. It's a pretty poor understanding on my part, so I'd recommend looking into it - probably understanding the Linux file structure would help. If you updated the Gnome Disk Utility to point to the paths you mounted, I'd be inclined to *think* it'd work... :)

Comment: So, from my UNIX days, /mnt was generally used for removeable media, network filesystems, or loopbacks. /mnt is where samba mounts, for example.  Everything permanent-looking mounted somewhere else.  Thanks...you answered the question.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/49400/119606 :)